# How to measure term constraint in sentence?

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, word2vec, sentence-similarity

I am trying to figure a way to algorithmically compute the informativeness of a word in a sentence based on how constrained the sentence is with that word missing. For example, how can I compute how much information the word "fox" provides in the sentence:

"the quick brown ___ jumped over the fence"

That is, in the absence of the target word, how can I compute how much more difficult it is for a user to fill in the blanks?

I have so far tried an approach where I look at the total word2vec semantic similarity of the target word with all of the surrounding words but that doesn't seem to work all the times. Is there any existing work that has been done on this?

Comment: You could use Machine Learning algorithms like Naive Bayes, or Artificial Neural Networks

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I would apply these approaches to this problem? I'm already using word2vec which uses a form of machine learning but it seems to be a rather crude solution. I was wondering if there is a more appropriate method for solving this problem.

Comment: You will to create initially create a database of all the expected test cases and use Naive Bayes for probability that a certain word shall occur. Based on the previous cases the result will be fetched

Comment: It seems like you would need to look at the frequency that different n-grams occur in the language. So for example, if 'quick brown fox' is an n-gram with a certain frequency, and there are no other tri-grams with 'quick brown ___' as the start, then the sentence might be constrained. However, if there were a lot of tri-grams that start 'quick brown ___' (i.e. 'quick brown monkey, 'quick brown dog', etc.) then the sentence would be less constrained.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work all the times, it's statistical. In best case, it would suggest something with some levels of confidence.